# mod_wsgi: Error "No such directory" for shutil.rmtree() after mkdtemp()

Tags: python, multithreading, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm really confusing about multiple thread in mod_wsgi, even after reading this [document](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading)

The main problem is that, how does mod_wsgi call my python scripts?

To make my question clear, i will conclude it to questions below

Suppose I have server configured like this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess XXX.com processes=12 threads=20 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup XXX.com
WSGIScriptAlias /sign /XXX/Http/upload.wsgi
```

And I'm using `prefork MPM`

And my `/XXX/Http/upload.wsgi` looks like this:

```
class app(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        temp_unsign = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        temp_signed = tempfile.mkdtemp()

        try:
            response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'),('Content-Length', str(len('123')))]
            status = '200 OK'
            start_response(status, response_headers)

            return ['123']
        finally:
            shutil.rmtree(temp_unsign)
            shutil.rmtree(temp_signed)

application = app()
```

Them my questions are:

1. If there're 5 requests from different IP at the same time, how many `app` instances will be there? One instance ? Or one instance per request
2. What if there're 5 requests from same IP and same computer at the same time?
3. Does all 5 `__call__` methods run in 5 different threads?

I ask this because I always get error `No such directory` when execute `shutil.rmtree`.

And of course, i can't understand how does mod_wsgi actually work in the matter of multiple thread